# Macbook internet blocked

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I have a macbook pro early 2015.

I'll put this in situation. I have internet connectivity, so I start working on pages. After a while, I see that iCloud doesn't sync. The Wi-fi icon looks like I'm connected to the internet, but I don't have internet access. I have to disable wi-fi and enable. After that, internet works.

I have an iPhone and there the internet works perfect.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Sounds like your router gets angry with the macbook pro. I'd check the network map when you're OK, and when your having the problem.

Comment: How to do that? With ifconfig?

Comment: Likely your router comes with a configuration App. Apple and Netgear routers do. In fact I've never met a plug and play router. Most at least give you firewall and MAC address filtering. That later may be your problem.